# Create multiple CGPath in a loop

Tags: objective-c, arrays, loops, nsdictionary, cgpath

I am creating a program containing a map, in order to check in which region a mouseDown is occurring I want to create a CGPath per region. For the moment I create this part :

```
int brestPoints[] = {755,751,684,765,655,851,586,905,607,940,718,898,716,954,741,960,743,938,775,925,761,872,767,815};

brest = CGPathCreateMutable();

for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(brestPoints); i=i+2) {
    if (i == 0) {
        CGPathMoveToPoint(brest, NULL, brestPoints[i], 2203-brestPoints[i+1]);
    } else {
        CGPathAddLineToPoint(brest, NULL, brestPoints[i], 2203-brestPoints[i+1]);
    }
}

CGPathCloseSubpath(brest);
```

My problem is that I have 75 CGPath to create and I would like to loop over multiple arrays to create them all at once.

The ideal solution for me would be to have a dictionary with an array for object and the name of the region for key. But I cannot put the arrays as object as it can only store objects.
Rewriting all 75 sets of coordinates to contain only NSNumber would be fastidious.

Any idea ?

**UPDATE**

I think there may subsist a confusion about what I'm trying to do, I have 75 C arrays like that :

```
int brestPoints[] = {755,751,684,765,655,851,586,905,607,940,718,898,716,954,741,960,743,938,775,925,761,872,767,815};
int picardyPoints[] = {769, 884, 778, 919, 859, 959, 956, 894, 949, 864, 864, 899, 842, 889};
```

I would need some way to create (simply) one NSBezierPath or CGPath for each array. And still know which Path belongs to which array (each array corresponds to one region of my map).

So I though of putting all of the arrays into a NSDictionary that would have an array associated with the region name as key. That way I could loop over the dictionary to create all my paths and still get to know the region they belong to. But I can seem to find a way to do that as C arrays can be put inside a NSDictionary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I'd do: Put the C arrays into a C array if they aren't already. Put the paths into an CFArray with the same order. Then you can just match the indices.

Answer (score -1):

Since you manually created the int arrays in a text editor, you can just use find/replace to format them into an NSDictionary literal with and NSArray of NSNumber values.

```
NSDictionary * regionPoints = { @"brest" : @[ @(1), @(2) ], 
                                @"picardy" : @[ @(1), @(2) ]};
```

Now you can construct `UIBezierPath` for UIKit (iOS) or `NSBezierPath` for AppKit (OSX) instead of `CGPath` objects. Add the NSBezierPath as the value in your dictionary. Once constructed, you no longer need access to the int arrays because NSBezierPath has methods for determining if a point is contained in the path as well as being able to draw the path.

Comment: I changed my code to use NSBezierPath (I'm using AppKit). But I still don't understand how to create all my NSBezierPath objects from my 75 arrays of coordinates. I tried putting all my arrays into a NSDictionary but it won't accept my arrays as they are ints and not objects.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: You construct the NSBezierPath and store it in an NSDictionary with your string key and then never need the int array again. NSBezierPath has methods for hit testing (determining if a point is in the path).

Comment: I understand that, but how can I create my 75 bezierPaths without writing 75 times the same piece of code ? I would like to use some kind of loop to do it on all my arrays at once.

Comment: You haven't shown how you get your 75 arrays. Are you just copy/pasting them from somewhere? Are you calling a function to get them as a result?

Comment: Sorry, my bad, my 75 arrays come from coordinates that I got from the coordinates in the image. So I wrote my 75 sets of coordinates and put them all in different arrays by hand. It was working fine with one area but is getting more tricky with 75 of them ...